# Change the displayed Group Name in the Data Veiw Web Part

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer

I created a Data View Web Part to display data from multiple sub sites using  Source Connection. I then grouped the data based on dates. (Example, the data for  1/31/2012 would show under one group and 2/1/2012 in another and  so on). Now the problem I am having is that group headings are displayed as ‘ows_Date: 2012-01:31 00:00:00’. I want them to display as ‘January 31, 2012’. 
How can I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set boundfield column property as below.

```
      DataFormatString ={0:D};
```

Thanks,